# Проблемы при установке visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Все начало с того момента, когда я попытался ее переустановить. Удалил прошлую студию, почистил реест через CCleaner, удалил все, что может быть с ней связано и начал установку 2015й студии. Первая из проблем - это то, что нельзя изменит путь установки. Вторая из проблем - это ошибка "KB2829760", после нескольких попыток чистить реестр и удалять все лишнее эта ошибка пропала, но появилась другая, теперь при установке происходит сбой кучи пакетов и в итоге VS не устанавливается. Но путь установки, кстати, по-прежнему недоступен. Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как ее решить?

Comment: устанавливал студию из образа, нисчем из перечисленного Вами не столкнулся.

Comment: Я устанавливаю с вэб установщика

Comment: Эта студия на столько мерзопакосна, что она везде. и в реетстре и в куче системных папок и не системных..... ошибка KB возможно потому, что что-то нет в `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`, что раньше было и нужно.....попробуйте прочесть https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/271809/   может поможет....... а вообще если есть откат системы - надо испробовать и сделать всё заново

Comment: Почитал статью на хабре, не помогло

Comment: @user213975 выложите хотя бы полный лог ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Был у меня похожий случай, номер KB уже не вспомню. Мне тогда помогло удаление VS, удаление всего, что вообще имеет хоть какое-то отношение к разработке (даже яву с фреймворком подтёр), затем чистка через CCleaner (как файлов, так и реестра), и потом уже ребут и установка VS заново и с нуля. Попробуйте, может и Вам поможет. Основано на личном опыте.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, замечательная утилита, которая почистит все после VS.
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases